# Download file to sdcard in android

Tags: android, https

I have a file stored in a internet site https://example.com (secured) Now if I have to download it to the SD CARD; is it the same process as a site that is on http:// (regular http) or any changes are needed?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3402463/1234007

Comment: When it comes to https it becomes a little tricky. You have to take in consideration the certificate.

Comment: Is the link you gave showing the difference in downloading files from `http` and `https` ?

Comment: yes but don't forget to add the below permissions to your Manifest.xml file : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 0):

There have no difference,same as http.

But don't forget the permission