# Downloading source programatically from github for phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, github

I am new to this forum so please forgive me if I am asking something stupid.

I have a mobile responsive website which is to be ported on mobile devices using PhoneGap. The code of mobile site is on github and I want to download the code from github in order to work in offline mode. This would help in keeping just one version of application on play store which will download content from github if there are any changes on website.

So, is there anyway I can download zip file from github using android APIs?

Thanks for reading.

Regards,
Anjali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much possible. Please see at the link below.

[How to download source in ZIP format from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-in-zip-format-from-github)

You need to use HttpURLConnection in order to download it to the location you want.

Cheers,
Bsengar

Answer (score 0):

The link for the actual zip file is available on GitHub.

It's possible to download a zip file using the HttpURLConnection. You should cache the zip(on SD card for example), and extract it. The code for downloading the zip is shown in this thread:
[Android Download Zip to SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402165/android-download-zip-to-sd-card)